# Save data in windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I want when closed app and reopen app save data in the app...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        textblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    }
```

I want add in this code save data in close the app?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it Windows Phone 8.1 RT? If yes then you can do that:

```
 var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
 if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("textblockVisibility"))
 {
     var value = localSettings.Values["textblockVisibility"];
     textblock.Visibility = (bool) value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
 }
 else
 {
      var valueToSave = textBlock.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
      localSettings.Values.Add("textblockVisibility", valueToSave);
 }
```